# System.UnauthorizedAccessException, trying to use XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This is the function I use to save the data. The data is stored inside `holder`(`SettingsHolder`). The directory I need is recognised but it does not have permission.

```
        //Save the data of a new user, called by NewUser();
        public static void SaveNew(string filename)
        {
            UserLogins.SettingsHolder holder = new UserLogins.SettingsHolder();

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            var XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserLogins.SettingsHolder));
            XML.Serialize(stream, holder);
        }
```

This is where I call `SaveNew`:

```
        public static void NewUser()
        {
            UserSlot = FindLastEmptyUser();

            // Set user default settings.
            Console.WriteLine(users[UserSlot]);
            Console.WriteLine("What will the new user's name be?");
            UserLogins.SettingsHolder.name = Console.ReadLine();
            users[UserSlot] = UserLogins.SettingsHolder.name;

            UserLogins.SettingsHolder.status = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Ok, I made a new user called " + users[UserSlot]);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            // Write defaults to XML file

            SaveNew(Environment.CurrentDirectory + users[UserSlot]);
            UserDataLoader.PromptUsers();
        }
```

I have tried the instructions of other people who have asked this question but they didn't work.

The exact error message is `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\(my user)\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\dotnet\dotnet1\bin`

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Why are you getting "C:\Users\(my user)\"  My users should be the login. Only the login user and admin have access.  If you want other to access the folder put on a network drive.

Comment: Ohhh i see, I had it stored inside my desktop to access my projects folder quickly, i didn't use a shortcut because I didnt think I needed to. I moved it to C:\ and it worked.

Comment: Most Windows Systems users do not have access to the root folder on c:\ drive.

Comment: Oh, that's weird because it managed to make it save successfully, thanks for the help though.

Comment: Are you an Admin?  Make sure other users can write to the root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, the file was in the Users(my user) directory so it did not have access, only the user and admins have access to that. I moved it to C:\ and it fixed itself.

I had the problem again on a different project so just in case that didn't work for other people, I had set `filename` to a directory, make sure it includes the name of the file as well as the directory

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Add the answer and explain why this is a good answer to make it more accessible for everyone

Comment: Sorry about that, just edited it